Fail to set a touchscreen in Device Tree
I'm trying to connect a touch controller via I2C to my DART6UL linux embedded board.
The follwoing if what I add to my device tree;
   egalax_ts@2a {
        compatible = "eeti,egalax_ts";
        reg = <0x2a>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio3>;
        interrupts = <4 2>; //IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW>;
        wakeup-gpios = <&gpio3 4 0>; //GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
    };

I noticed the following errors in bootlog:
egalax_ts 1-002a: Failed to read firmware version
egalax_ts: probe of 1-002a failed with error -5

They seem to be related at the 0x2a (i.e the touch controller address).
May be something is not correctly set, since also the pin used as INT for touch was fixed LOW.
Any suggestion?

Did you include that device tree section in the correct i2c bus (beware of numbering offset)? Can you see device on that bus using i2cdetect?
